# How can I avoid asking twitter to grant access for my app everytime the user signs in to my website?

Tags: twitter-oauth, twitterizer

I am using Twitterizer which works great. I have a website (.NET 4, C#) where a user visits and signs-in... I store tokens e.t.c everything works great.

The question is how can I avoid asking the user to grant access to my app via twitter since I already did this once the first time (and let's say user is already signed in twitter in a different tab on my browser)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=zyx` instead of `/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xyz`.

Read more on the [Sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing) and [GET oauth/authenticate](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authenticate) documentation.

Comment: Thanks it works!...but when using OAuthUtility.BuildAuthorizationUri it always generates "authorize" URL and can't find any other method to generate "authorize" for twitterizer except from replacing that string.

Comment: You will probably have to look at the library docs, source, or ask the maintainer about it.

Comment: The BuildAuthorizationUri method can take 1 or 2 parameters. The 2nd parameter is "bool authenticate". Provide 'true' to this 2nd parameter and the method will provide you with the authenticate url. (FYI: I am the maintainer.)